# Filtering file list to show only files alphabetically after certain file

Tags: bash, files, ffmpeg, filter

I have a huge number of images from which I'd like to feed some to `ffmpeg` time to time.
But I **only** want to feed ones that are alphabetically **after** certain image (last frame of previous run, name stored in some file).

Can I for example find out an order/index number of that one file and then do `head`/`tail` using that number?

Or is there some magical `-pattern_type glob` I could use as `ffmpeg -i` parameter?

Best filtering solution so far seems to be this but it seems a bit *heavy*:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort |  awk '$0 > "./picture_2022-04-22_13-46-12.jpg"'
```

One alternative would be to put the list into text file, do parsing there and feed the text file to ffmpeg but I'd like to think there is some simpler way?

Comment: don't process `find` output like this: file names can contain line breaks! use `find -print0`, and `sort -z` to use zero-byte as entry delimited. Or, don't use `find` and sort at all, but rely on your shell's globbing, which seems to be the wiser choice here. If you use find, it has arguments to find only files newer than a reference file, which seems to be exactly what you want here, as well, and would get rid of the sorting and `awk`.

Comment: Can you use the file's modification date instead of the date in the file name?

Comment: @terdon: I could use date as well, yes. Just thought that filename would be most straightforward. And in this case I need to store the name (or date?) of the last processed frame to a tmp file for the next run.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Very good points! (Though in this case I can fully control the input filename format). Using the `find` parameter to find newer than reference file sounds like the right way too, will need to look into that indeed..

Comment: Will `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer reference-file` do the trick?

Comment: @Philippos: That does indeed smoothen things out a lot! No need to call `awk` anymore. Still seem to need the `| sort` or else results seem all random.

Comment: What was wrong with ` ls | awk '$0 > "after.jpg"'`?

Comment: @Tigger: Oh sh.. Nothing wrong with that indeed, seems to do exactly the same thing! Don't know how my googling came up with that `find | sort | awk` thing and not just `ls`.

So this works as intended:
`ls *.jpg | awk -v var="$lastframe" '$0 > var'`

With ffmpeg the whole thing is:
```ffmpeg -y -r 60 -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '$PWD/%s'\n" $(ls *.jpg | awk -v var="$lastframe" '$0 > var')) -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=60,format=yuv420p" "$savepath/output.mp4"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sorting, some `sed` or `awk` could be used to match from pattern until the end of the stream. I assume that your final `ffmpeg` command accepts a list of file arguments. I use a `printf` instead of `ffmpeg` below.

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | sed -nz '/pattern/,$p' | xargs -r0 printf '%s\n'
```

GNU arguments separation is used. `sed` command filters the sorted arguments, from pattern (including) to the end of the stream.

If you want to get files from pattern until, not the end, but until a second pattern, the only modification is for the `sed`, it becomes `sed -zn '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'`.

A shorter alternative for your case (depth 1) where we don't test for regular files, would be:

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.jpg | sed -nz '/pattern/,$p' | xargs -r0 printf '%s\n'
```

Here the files are already alphabetically sorted after the first step.

Also, you can compare with a string, not necessarily existing in the filenames, excluding or including, preferably using `awk` like you already do. For example, get all files named with a date later than `2022-01`:

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.jpg | awk 'BEGIN {RS=ORS="\0"} $0 > "./picture_2022-01"' | xargs -r0 printf '%s\n'
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick too, thank you! As a minor curiosity it does seem to include the _pattern_ (and potential _pattern2_) in the results list while the `awk >` method does not.

Comment: Yes. You can exclude the pattern also. Note that pattern muxt exists in the file, a date existing into a filename. If you compare (like your awk) there is no need the pattern to exist, eg compare with `2022-02`. I will update the answer with an awk example.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
last=picture_2022-04-22_13-46-12.jpg
# or last=$(<file_that_contains_the_filename)
ffmpeg ... picture_*.jpg(e['[[ $REPLY > $last ]]'])
```

That's using the `e`valuate [*glob qualifier*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to limit the glob expansion to those files for which the evaluated code returns true.

See also `[[ $REPLY -nt $last ]]` to select files `n`ewer `t`han `$last` (similar to `find -newer`).

With `bash`, you could do something similar with:

```
last=picture_2022-04-22_13-46-12.jpg
(
  shopt -s nullglob
  files=()
  for file in picture_*.jpg; do
    if [[ $file > $last ]]; then
      files+=("$file")
    fi
  done
  if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
    ffmpeg ... "${files[@]}"
  else
    echo >&2 No match; exit 1
  fi
)
```